# Csv File does not exist (Ubuntu Subsystem)

Tags: python, csv

I am using an Ubuntu subsytem on Windows 10.
I have a .csv file in this folder.

`C:\Users\JinKazama\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\home\jdinco`

Howeever, when I try to open it with `data = pd.read_csv()` it's not working. I tried changing the direction of the slashes and using double slashes instead of one , but it's still not working. The two types of error I am getting:

with

```
data = pd.read_csv(r'csvfile.csv')
```

it`s the following:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'C:\\Users\\jeankazama\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\\LocalState\\rootfs\\home\\jdinco\\abcnews.csv' does not exist: b'C:\\Users\\jeankazama\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\\LocalState\\rootfs\\home\\jdinco\\abcnews.csv'
```

with

```
data = pd.read_csv('csvfile.csv')
```

the error is:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Please help thank you very much.

​

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [format your question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to get more answers.

Comment: try os.path.join instead of slash es, here is a good reference : [link](https://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_files.php)